# Access collection in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm using entrust for my roles and permissions on laravel 5.2 and I have this on my controller:

```
$user = Auth::user();
    $rol = $user->roles;
    dd($rol);
```

in my User model:

```
 public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Nini\Role','role_user');
}
```

And get this: [Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRFBs.png)

I'm tryng to acces and show "display_name" on my view and i can't, help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you have defined in your User model, a user could has many roles (which means a user has an array of roles), so you have to define of which role you want to display the display_name property. I you want to show the display_name property for all available roles for a user, this could be achieved with something like:

```
@foreach (Auth::user()->roles as $rol)
  $rol->display_name
@endforeach
```

I hope it helps to clear your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

For see data in controller use `$user = Auth::user()->with('roles')`

use `dd($rol->toArray())` for check data collection,

Comment: An error:Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$roles

Answer (score 0):

To get all the roles of user in comma separated then you can [use `implode()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-implode) as:

```
$rol->implode('display_name', ', ');
```

then it gives you `Admin, Manager`

Answer (score 0):

As I think **[Laravel's Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)** library has Many to Many Relationship between user and roles.
So if you want to show the display name on your view you've to fetch items/objects from the collection you get from calling the method **roles()**
You can do this as:

```
// Collection of Roles
$user_roles = $user->roles;
foreach($user_roles as $user_role) {
  echo $user_role->display_name;
}
```

Or if you want to fetch the first rle you can use

`$user_roles->first()->display_name`

I hope this helps you!